# Liquibase - ignore old changesets

Tags: migration, liquibase

I am having trouble with Liquibase. For some reason (i didn't change any existing changesets or something) it is attempts to apply changesets which is already in base. So i am getting the errors like `"relation "table" already exists"`.

I found this tag - `<validCheckSum>`, but it seems that it is only for new checksums of changesets. What i want to do is to ignore some changeset if there is some checksum in `databasechangelog`. For example, i tried `<validCheckSum>f24567a5f86276f22cb8c5a8eddf25a4</validCheckSum>` but migration with this checksum (in table `databasechangelog`) still runs and fails.

UPD: If i run my changeset on empty database i can see that checksum did not changed. Still it tries to perform the migrations which is already complete one some non empty database.

Answer (score 2):

Checksum of the changeSet changes when your change the logic of your changeSet (everything besides preconditions, contexts, and validCheckSum). Check out this article [What Affects ChangeSet Checksums?](https://www.liquibase.org/blog/what-affects-changeset-checksums)

You can execute [liquibase:clearCheckSums](https://docs.liquibase.com/tools-integrations/maven/commands/maven-clearchecksums.html) command. It will recalculate the checksums of your changeSets and store their values in `databasechangelog` table, thus problem solving your problem.

You can use `<validCheckSum>any</validCheckSum>` if you don't want to deal with changing checksums in future, but it's **not** a good idea, since you're looking the integrity check for your changeSet.

Comment: That is the problem - i did not changed any of my changesets. I added one new changeset and updated the version of liquibase. I also tried to just execute my changesets on empty table - the checksum is the same. But it still attempts to run migrations which is already in databasechangelock.

Comment: @DenisNovac What versions of Liquibase did you upgrade from and to? If you moved from Liquibase 2 to Liquibase 3, then there are changes to the way in which checksums are calculated, which may be something to do with it.

Comment: @JonBetts it was 3.6.3 to 3.9.0. And the checksums seems the same. I run it on empty tables and see the same checksum as in my original database.